# Error reporting in Test Automation FX

Tags: c#, error-reporting, testautomationfx

I create automated tests with [Test Automation FX](http://www.testautomationfx.com/) and I'm beginner.

I need to know how to fail test from within test script?

I am using C# scripting.

Say if I want to recognize some window control and have to perform action on that:

```
if(window["Exists"])
{
    //Perform action.
}
else
{
    // move to the next test cases.
}
```

I don't know how to handle the else part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To report failure of test case when window does not exist you can use following methods of of [Verify](http://www.testautomationfx.com/Help/html/T_TestAutomationFX_Core_Verify.htm) class from [*Test Automation FX* API](http://www.testautomationfx.com/Help/html/R_Project.htm):

- [`FailTest`](http://www.testautomationfx.com/Help/html/M_TestAutomationFX_Core_Verify_FailTest.htm)
- [`AreEqual`](http://www.testautomationfx.com/Help/html/M_TestAutomationFX_Core_Verify_AreEqual.htm)

with `FailTest` method:

```
    if (window["Exist"])
    {
        // Perform actions
    }
    else
    {
        Verify.FailTest("Window does not exist"); // Report failure message that will be shown in test report
    }
```

with `AreEqual` method:

```
    Verify.AreEqual(window["Exist"], true); // will fail test if window dows not exist
    // Perform actions
```